# How to use modal by the help of shared module?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use a common modal in several components, for that i ahve created

TestResultComponent.ts and TestResultComponent.html => for modal

to use it in several components i have declared and exported in sharedmodule.ts as

```
  @NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [SearchComponent, TestResultComponent],
    exports: [SearchComponent, TestResultComponent],
})
```

and in components where i need to use the modal i have used shared module.

but  i need to use

```
 @ViewChild('testModal') testModal: TestResultComponent;
```

in my directive, so i have imported the TestResultComponent explicitly like

```
import { TestResultComponent } from '../../shared/test-result/test-result.component';
```

but now i am getting error like

```
Unexpected directive 'TestResultComponent' imported by the module 'SharedModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

it may be due to i am using 'TestResultComponent' again in every components by importing.

How can i fix this?